# Relating convergence theorem for Newton-Raphson method to Newton fractal

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods, fractals

I have created a Newton fractal (below) using the Newton-Raphson method to find the five solutions of

`f = (z^5-1)`

The convergence theorem of Newtons method say "Suppose that f is smooth and that
f(x) = 0 and f'(x) =/= 0. Then, there exists epsilon > 0 so that Newton’s method converges to the root x of f if the initial guess x 0 ∈ [x − epsilon, x + epsilon]."

However, I am struggling to see how the epsilon relates to the plot I have made. How could I determine an epsilon value for this? And is it possible to have epsilon as a complex number? Would this still create a circle surrounding x0?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's pretty!

Comment: I once made an effort to visually compare the easily programmable methods in https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~llehmann/topics/newton-fractal/ . As can be seen, Newton's method produces by far the most "interesting" fractals, i.e., the most clutter at the borders of the basins of attraction.

Comment: Rather than go pick flowers for my girlfriend, I think I should just generate them from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relation is this:

> For each root there is a small disk around the root whose points have all the same color.

You can find a suitable radius $\varepsilon$ by inspection from the picture.

Joel Friedman in [On the Convergence of Newton's Method](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~jf/pubs/web_stuff/convergence.html) (Theorem 2.2) gives an explicit radius for such a disk for a polynomial $f$:
$$
r=\frac{\eta}{2d}
$$
where $\eta$ is the minimum distance between two roots of $f$ and $d$ is the degree of $f$.

Other explicit bounds are given by Anthony Manning in [How to be sure of finding a root of a complex polynomial using Newton's method](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01232940) (Theorem 1.2).

See also [How to find all roots of complex polynomials by Newton's method](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002220100149)  by Hubbard et al.
*Invent. Math.* 146 (2001), no. 1, 1–33. [pdf](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/NewtonInventiones.pdf)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/34581/.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I was unaware of such a simple bound. I wonder if there is a similar result for rational functions as well?  In practice, I typically try to find a positive $\varepsilon$ such that $|N'(x)|<1$ for all $x$ within $\varepsilon$ of the root.  This not too hard to code, but certainly must take much longer than using a simple bound like the one that you state here.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, I'm not aware of a similar result for rational functions. I'd love to know one.